# Get all rows from table A where no matching row exist in table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

Apologies, wasn't really sure what to put for the title of this one, I think it's a bit more complex than it sounds. This question is for Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

I have two tables that look like this:

#### Logging.Logs:

```
+---------+------------+--------------+
|  LogID  |  LogEntry  |  LogTimeUtc  |
+---------+------------+--------------+
|  1      |  Foo       |  2015-10-16..|
|  2      |  Bar       |  2015-10-16..|
|  ...    |  ...       |  ...         |
```

#### Logging.LogAttributes:

```
+---------+------------------+----------------+
|  LogID  |  LogAttributeID  |  LogAttribute  |
+---------+------------------+----------------+
|  1      |  1               |  FooAttribute  |
|  1      |  2               |  BarAttribute  |
|  1      |  3               |  BazAttribute  |
|  2      |  1               |  FooAttribute  |
|  2      |  2               |  BazAttribute  |
|  ...    |  ...             |  ...           |
```

I want all of the LogIDs from Logging.Logs that don't have a corresponding entry in Logging.LogAttributes with a LogAttribute field that starts with 'Bar'.

In the tables above, I would just get LogID 2, because LogID 1 has a row in in LogAttributes with 'BarAttribute' in the LogAttribute field.

I started with a left join, but it returns 1 and 2 because there are entries in LogAttributes with LogID 1 and LogAttribute not starting with 'Bar'

```
SELECT *
FROM Logging.Logs l
LEFT JOIN Logging.LogAttributes la
ON ( l.LogID = la.LogID AND la.LogAttribute NOT LIKE 'Bar%' )
```

Comment: Is LogAttributes.LogID nullable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
SELECT *
FROM Logging.Logs l
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
     (SELECT * 
      FROM Logging.LogAttributes la 
      WHERE l.LogID = la.LogID AND la.LogAttribute LIKE 'Bar%' )
```

Comment: All answers were good thanks, this one used NOT EXISTS which I believe is better, so I chose this one as the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to revise your JOIN statement:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM Logging.Logs l
LEFT JOIN Logging.LogAttributes la ON l.LogID = la.LogID AND la.LogAttributeID LIKE 'Bar%'
WHERE la.LogID IS NULL
```

With proper indexes, it should be *much* faster than `EXISTS` and `IN` queries.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01ce4/1)

Answer (score 0):

You should simply do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM Logging.Logs L
WHERE L.LogID NOT IN (SELECT la.LogID 
                      FROM Logging.LogAttributes La
                      WHERE la.LogAttribute LIKE 'Bar%' )
```

Comment: extra bracket is there... remove that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Logging.Logs l Where l.LogId Not In ( Select la.LogId From Logging.LogAttributes la, Logging B Where 
la.LogID = B.LogID AND la.LogAttribute NOT LIKE 'Bar%' )
```

Caution : NOT IN queries may have performance issues for large datasets.

Update : NOT Exists can be better than NOT IN.

Comment: Is not exists any better? I am working against a large dataset.

Comment: Yes, Not exists _is_ better. I should've mentioned it.